# Mailbox name not allowed. The Server response was: 5.7.1 <sender@abcd.com>:Sender address rejected:not logged in

Tags: c#, email, smtp, smtpclient, smtp-auth

Created simple tool to send test mails in c# as below
but getting error as

> Mailbox name not allowed. The Server response was: 5.7.1
>   :Sender address rejected:not logged in

Currently i am using internal networks(sending mail using intranet.i.e. using private email server)

it is working fine with Microsoft outlook but not with my code or using telnet

config:
port no:25

```
 try
            {

                using (MailMessage mm = new MailMessage(txtEmail.Text, txtTo.Text))
                {
                    mm.Subject = txtSubject.Text;
                    mm.Body = txtBody.Text;



                    mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
                    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();

                    smtp.Host = txtHostName.Text;

                    //0001_013896_642014_642014.pdf
                    if (chkEnable.Checked)
                    {
                        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        smtp.EnableSsl = false;
                    }
                    NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new NetworkCredential(txtEmail.Text, txtPassword.Text);
                    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                    smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
                    smtp.Port = Convert.ToInt32(txtPortNO.Text);

                    smtp.Send(mm);
                    MessageBox.Show("Mail send at:" + DateTime.Now.ToString());

                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                MessageBox.Show("error Occured:" + e.Message); 
            }
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Solved by Setting/Configuration of Display name (sender name/email setting)
due to this sender name is not visible to smtp server

Comment: Can you elaborate how you fixed this issue with steps. Facing same error